# htaccess redirect url/domain to my server using ip address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a web server with a website on the root IIS7 So it is wwwroot/mysite. This web server has about 20+ websites on. So I have a domain and only have access to it via ftp. Its Apache LAMP based stuff.

So I need to redirect www.mydomain.co.uk to my IP address 107.xxx.xxx.xxx and then to the right binding all from a .htaccess file.

Is this at all possible? Sounds a bit hacky to me. Currently I am just redirect www.mydomain.co.uk to www.mydomain2.co.uk. Maybe there is a way to mask the url.

Thank you in advance for any advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a domain, you could set a subdomain that points to the IP address of your server (107.xxx.xxx.xxx) and have everything else point to the other server.  Then, you can set up an A record (if you have access to DNS editing from your domain registrar -- not your website host), to point the subdomain to your IP address (I'm currently doing this on one of my subdomains to point to my linux VoIP box while everything else points to my website).

I honestly don't know if PHP alone can accomplish this, but I know from experience that DNS Zones can.